# How do I authenticate that a user is logged into BigCommerce in a custom API?

Tags: bigcommerce

We have a BigCommerce Stencil theme which needs to connect to some custom endpoints we built. How do we authenticate that the user is logged into BigCommerce and identify their BigCommerce user information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @adamf321 have you tried using the BigCommerce CurrentCustomer API?
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/current-customer-api
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/storefront/current-customers

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what we were looking for!

Comment: Is there a JWKS endpoint available that we can use to validate a BigCommerce customer against my own external verification system?

Comment: @adamf321 https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D54O00006n2sTCSAY/get-public-jwt-for-customer-api-login thread may be helpful in regards to JWKS. Check out the thread and feel free to contribute to the thread if you found this was helpful or if you went a different direction.